# Inverse trigonometry and differential equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I was looking for the solution of the differential equation :

$$x \sin (y/x)dy - (y \arcsin (y/x) - x )dx = 0.$$

I know this is a homogenous differential equation of degree 0 but while solving the integral I came to stage where I was confused:

substituing $y=vx$ and simplifying I got,

$$\frac{\sin v dv}{v \arcsin v - 1 -v\sin v} = \frac{dx}{x}$$ and after that I know I have to Integrate both the sides, but I am unable to do so. Please help me out the with the solution of this equation.

Comment: I edited your question to typeset fomulas with MathJax. You might want to recheck these formulas to verify that they represent what you wanted to say.

Comment: @ Shashank Dwivedi $$x=c\:e^{\int \frac{\sin(v)dv}{-v\sin (v) +v \arcsin (v) - 1}dv}$$ You can't integrate because there is probably no closed form for the integral.